# how to get rid off the error ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception?

Tags: java, exception

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3}; // it gives me arrayindexoutofboundexception

    int length = numbers[3];

    char[] chars = new char[length];

    chars[numbers.length + 4] = 'y';

    System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

}

How to remove array index out of bound exception .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't access `numbers[3];` when your array has only 3 elements, whose indices are 0, 1 and 2.

Also don't access `chars[numbers.length + 4]` before making sure this is a valid index of the `chars` array.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped.
what if i try to catch the exception,then it get compiled without exception but there is no output,can you explain,thanks?

Comment: @KedarKholiya Don't catch the exception. You should avoid it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
int length = numbers[3];
```

To:

```
int length = numbers[2];
```

Comment: done,but no help.giving runtime error

Comment: @KedarKholiya - Check *Eran's* answer. The line `chars[numbers.length + 4] = 'y';` is *suicidal*.